# Deploy API to sub folder

Tags: api, subdirectory

I' new to the world of APIs. I have successfully created an API that links to SQL and brings back data, this is deployed at the top level of the domain.

for example

> Doman.co.uk/mfr (lists manufacturers)
>       Doman.co.uk/models(lists models)

All works fine.

I've then copied the VS solution and added another model and controller so that  I know have a project that contains models and controller for mfr, models and parts. Again all works if I deploy/publish to top level.

However, I would like to publish to a subfolder. i.e the URL to access the API would be.

> Doman.co.uk/subfolder/mfr (lists manufacturers)
>     Doman.co.uk/subfolder/models(lists models)
>     Doman.co.uk/subfolder/parts(lists models)

Essentially creating versioning, but when I try and access the API from the sub folder, it thinks the name of the sub folder is the controller and fails.

Any ideas?

I'm using .Net 4.5 and c#
I can post more information if needed and code you let me know what would help you, to help me.And Thank you to anyone in advance who takes the time to look at my problem.

To summerise. 
I would like the old API available from the top level domanin.co.uk/controller
and the new version available from doman.co.uk/subfolder/controller.

**Update**

I have uploaded my version two of the API to a different location and used IIS to add this as a virtual directory under the main site. Now I have the problem.

**The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUr**

Comment: So I would like to end up with the Original API available from Domain.co.uk/controller and I would like the new version available from Domain.co.uk/v2/ controller

Comment: I have made progress. I have deployed the API to another location and that works. I have then linked to this location as a virtual directory for my main site. However when I do this I get the error.   The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUr..   I do not get this error when I access the location directly